# Pandas find Row number for matching values

Tags: python, pandas

I can find the matching row with this but how do I get the row number of the df?

```
y = df.loc [ df [ 'month' ] == df3 [ 'month' ] ]
```

I need y to be the row count.

I can get the index value, but the index for df is also a date.

Thanks.

Comment: adging index at the end ?

Comment: As in `df.index [ df [ 'month' ] == df3 [ 'month' ] ]`?

Comment: need the row of df['month'] when it  == df3 [ 'month' ]

Comment: in this case the df.index will be the same as df['month'].

Comment: Index([2013-04-30], dtype='object', name='month').  need to convert to a iloc value

Comment: How about a [mcve] with some data and output? This isn't enough to answer your question, not nearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **don't want to reset the index** you can simply add a column with a row count:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'month':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2]})
df.insert(0, 'row_num', range(0,len(df)))  # here you insert the row count
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'month':[2,2,2,1,2,2,2]})
y = df.loc [ df [ 'month' ] == df3 [ 'month' ] ]
```

The content of the `df`

```
>>> df
   row_num  month
0        0      1
1        1      1
2        2      1
3        3      1
4        4      2
5        5      2
6        6      2
```

Result

```
>>> y['row_num']
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
```

Comment: I went with this approach. it actually solved a much bigger issue with the df that I was having in other places also.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One method is [reindexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) since you want the index to be integers rather than dates.

```
y = df.loc[df['month'] == df3['month' ]].reset_index().index
```